# Como pesquisar usando expressão regular no delphi 7

Tags: delphi, regex, algoritmo-de-busca, delphi-7

No delphi 7 ao abrir a caixa de diálogo de busca: CTRL + F e selecionando a opção: Regular Expressions gostaria de encontrar tudo que começasse com a palavra **GPField** e terminasse com **IsNull**

Por exemplo, tenho o sequinte código:

```
if GPField('TABELATAXAS').IsNull then 
if GPField('TABELACARNE').IsNull then
```

Gostaria de pesquisar algo do tipo:

```
GPField*IsNull
```

O que me traria as duas linhas de código acima.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

```
GPField.*IsNull
```

A expressão será *true* para qualquer caractere (`.`) que apareça 0 ou *n* vezes (`*`) entre `GPField` e `IsNull`, trazendo as linhas que você mencionou na sua pergunta.